# Convergence Rate of Quantile from Convergence Rate of Distribution

Tags: convergence, asymptotics, quantiles

Suppose we have a sequence of distribution functions $F_n$ such that $F_n \rightarrow F$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. Suppose that we know the convergence rate, given by 
$$
\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} | F(x) - F_n(x) | \le G(n)
$$
where $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} G(n) = 0$.

I'd like to know if there is a method to derive the convergence rate of quantiles at a percentile $\alpha$:
$$q_\alpha = \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{x: F(x) \ge \alpha \} = F^{-1}(\alpha)$$
$$q_{n,\alpha} = \inf_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \{x: F_n(x) \ge \alpha \} = F_n^{-1}(\alpha)$$

It is in fact the case that $q_{n,\alpha} \rightarrow q_\alpha$ if $F_n \rightarrow F$ (proved in Proposition 5 (page 250) in *A Modern Approach to Probability Theory* by Bert Fristedt and Lawrence Gray, for example). However, I'm interested in the *rate* of convergence for the quantile, if we have a rate of convergence for the distribution function.
Given the above, how can we find a function $H(n)$ such that
 $$
|q_\alpha - q_{n,\alpha}| \le H(n) ?
$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "have one for the distribution function"? Does this mean the $\alpha$ quantile $F^{-1}(\alpha)$ is unique?

Comment: Added clarification. I just meant if we have a given convergence rate for the distribution function, is there a way to translate this information to the quantile function. And yes, lets assume that everything has "nice" properties and that the quantile function is unique.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled about this, because the quantile *as defined in the quotation* is unique.  The distributions $F$ that cause problems are pretty nice mathematically: they are the ones where for the $\alpha$ in question there exist multiple $x$ for which $F(x)=\alpha.$